# XSLT Concatenate element values

Tags: xslt-2.0

My requirement is to concatenate values coming at run time in the ref element. I could get separate values for each element and the concatenate it but still i will miss out text in between.

I have edited my questions as per suggestion made by Martin.

Here is my input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rootelement>
<nref ref="f1"/>    <nref ref="f2"/>    <nref ref="f3"/>
<nref ref="f4"/>    <nref ref="f5"/>
<pnotes>
<pnote id="f1">
    <p>Some Text.</p>
</pnote>
<pnote id="f2">
    <p><ref><year>1812</year>, <vol>3</vol><series>F. &amp;
            F.</series><pages>22</pages></ref>, at p. 27.</p>
</pnote>
<pnote id="f3">
    <p><ref>[<year>1914</year>],
        <vol>2</vol><series>A.B.C.</series><pages>94</pages></ref>.</p>
</pnote>
<pnote id="f4">
    <p><ref><year>1955</year>,
        <vol>2</vol><series>A.B.C</series><pages>509</pages></ref>.</p>
</pnote>
<pnote id="f5">
    <p><ref>[<year>1805</year>], <series>A.C.</series><pages>21</pages>     </ref>.</p>
</pnote>
</pnotes></rootelement>
```

I have tried following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="nref">
    <xsl:variable name="ref" select="@ref"/>
    <noteref>
        <xsl:for-each select="//pnotes/pnote">
            <xsl:if test="@id = $ref">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </noteref>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//pnotes[not(pnotes)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result i get is not correct.

I need spaces in between the text.

Result :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <rootelement>
    <noteref> Some Text. </noteref>
    <noteref> 1812, 3F. &amp; F.22, at p. 27. </noteref>
    <noteref> [1914], 2A.B.C.94. </noteref>
    <noteref> 1955, 2A.B.C509. </noteref>
    <noteref> [1805], A.C.21. </noteref>
 </rootelement>
```

Required Result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootelement>
<noteref> Some Text. </noteref>
<noteref> 1812, 3 F. &amp; F. 22, at p. 27. </noteref>
<noteref> [1914], 2 A.B.C. 94. </noteref>
<noteref> 1955, 2 A.B.C 509. </noteref>
<noteref> [1805], A.C.21. </noteref>
</rootelement>
```

Can somebody help me please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over  elemnts and anyone of them have square brackets:

When you make your first iteration, you get the element `<year>` and its value is 1902, not [1902]. Your square brackets are in the element `<noteref>`.

Change your XML to store the year as [1902] or change your for-each to print the square brackets manually.

Answer (score 0):

Simply output the string value of the element to get all text, if you don't want the line breaks the also normalize the string:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ref">
      <noteref>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
      </noteref>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Result is

```
<rootelement>
<pnote>
    <P>
        <noteref>[1902], A.C. 12</noteref>.</P>
</pnote>
<pnote>
    <P>
        <noteref>1902 B.A. 98</noteref>.</P>
</pnote>
<pnote>
    <P> This is a text </P>
</pnote>
<pnote>
    <P>
        <noteref>[1912], 1 R.B. 160</noteref>, at pp. 165, 169.</P>
</pnote>
</rootelement>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/b4GWV2.

Comment: When i use normalize-space() with sample example it works fine but when i run against actual XML it removes spaces from noteref element. Can you please suggest.

Comment: Well, then edit your question and provide the sample data and the corresponding output you want, together with an explanation which white space you want to keep and which you want to remove or collapse. If you use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>` then I am sure no spaces are removed, but then you will also keep line breaks and your samples posted so far appear to indicate you want to collapse them.

Comment: Hi Martin - I have edited my questions as per your suggestion. Thanks for help

Comment: I have tried to implement the output a bit differently  in http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/eiQZDbc but it is still not what you have posted as the wanted result. I am not sure where that result comes from, you have spaces between `vol` and `series` which are not in the input and I have not been able to identify any rules when to insert spaces and when not.